# Session array accessing on next button click of next button

Tags: php, mysql

How to get next array element from session array on next button click?
I tried `next($_SESSION['qid'])` it didn't work

```
if((int)$_SESSION['qn']<=20) {
  $_SESSION['qn']=$_SESSION['qn']+1;
  $_SESSION['qid']++;
}
```

I also tried

```
$_SESSION['qid']=next($_SESSION['qid']);
```

But this neither worked. Can someone help me?

Comment: Show some code, what have you done to solve the problem?

Comment: try this,next($_SESSION)

Comment: but on the page there are different session elements i tried but not working

Comment: no idea what you are trying to achive

Comment: actually i am trying to fetch data from mysql to userscreen on next button click its quiz application so on next button click i need to pull next question whose id stored in session array.

Answer (score 2):

_SESSION array is an associative array. You can't access it by numeric index, but you must specify the index name (e.g. in your code, `$_SESSION['qid']`). Anyway, you can still use `next()` function, passing the array `$_SESSION` (see here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php). The correct way to use it is:

```
$element = next($_SESSION)
```

you'd likely want to put this code in a cycle.

Additionally, your code:

```
$_SESSION['qn']=$_SESSION['qn']+1;
```

means: assign to `$_SESSION['qn']` the value of `$_SESSION['qn']` plus `1`, which is not what you want.
In case you'd want the next element in a NON associative array, you should use:

```
$arr = $arr[$i+1]
```

where `$i` is a integer value.

**Update**: regarding your comment, why don't you save a regular array (non associative) inside `$_SESSION['questions']`? This way you'd have the questions accessible this way:

```
$_SESSION['questions'][0], $_SESSION['questions'][1]...
```

Now you can use it within a cycle, or whatever you want. E.g.:

echo $_SESSION['questions'][$current_question_id+1];

where `$current_question_id` would be the current question index, which will be updated (+1) every clic on the next button

Comment: actually i am trying to fetch data from mysql to userscreen on next button click its quiz application so on next button click i need to pull next question whose id stored in session array.

Comment: next two records only not third onwards

Comment: your question is very unclear. I can't understand what you're trying to achieve. You keep saying "next", but you can't explain "next" in respect to what. You didn't say the format of $_SESSION['qn'].. we can't help you that much. That's also the reason why some people gave you negative votes on your question.

Comment: i dnt need any points or positive marks just need solution.thanks for your reply.

Comment: it's not about the points. it's about your unclear question which you're not helping anyone to understand. good luck..